# Calling webservice and WCF in windows phone?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, windows-phone-7

I seen one method of web service that is to call from a MCWebServiceSoapClient.

```
//getting the different points for the map when checkbox is checked
private void polyc_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    testingwcf.MCWebServiceSoapClient ob = new TestMap.testingwcf.MCWebServiceSoapClient();
    ob.getPolytechnicPointsAsync();
    ob.getPolytechnicPointsCompleted += new EventHandler<testingwcf.getPolytechnicPointsCompletedEventArgs>(ob_getPolyPointsCompleted);
}
```

However what I am implementing to call is WCF. How to do convert this method to a WCF ? My WCF is here http://kailun92wcf.cloudapp.net/Service1.svc. Is it possible to call from a WCF into windows phone ersi map ? To plot the points ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to consume a WCF service from a WP app?

Firstly, generate your client proxy via visual studio, right click on "references", select "Add service reference", select the "Go" button, this wizard should discover your service if it is online.

Select the advanced button, and select the options below

[image]

[image]

in your code behind, hook up to a click event,

```
private void LoadWebService(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      var service =  new Service1Client();

      service.getRecommendPlaceAsync(new getRecommendPlaceRequest { activityId = 1}); //Provide your id here

      service.getRecommendPlaceCompleted += new EventHandler<MyCloundService.getRecommendPlaceCompletedEventArgs>(RecommendedPlaceRequestComplete);
    }

    void RecommendedPlaceRequestComplete(object sender, MyCloundService.getRecommendPlaceCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            var result = String.Join(",", (from place in e.Result.getRecommendPlaceResult select place.Name).ToArray());

            MessageBox.Show(result);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occured: " + e.Error.Message);
        }
    }
```

See a tutorial [here](http://prathapk.net/consuming-wcf-service-in-windows-phone-application/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you are trying to do is call a function on the phone from the WCF service you cant use event handlers over the wire like that especially not on a phone.

Because the phones run on battery you may want to use something like push notifications as detailed below:

[Sending push notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202945%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[Setting up your app to receive push notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)